# Android inject touch event

Tags: android, touch, motionevent

I know this is a bit repeating question. I have reviewed various questions on SO and few other sites but could not find a single answer that satisfies my need.

**Requirement**

1) I have X,Y coordinates, I want to **create MotionEvent and dispatch it to topmost activity/view.**

2) I have to inject it in my own App. So **Inject_Events permission should not be required**.

3) While I have the coordinates, **I do not know, Activity or View which are at that position. So Activity.dispatchTouchEvent does not work for me.**. (view.dispatchTouchEvent will work but I do not know the view).

4) **Instrumentation does not help either** because they do not have single method to inject touch event at x,y location.

5) InputManager has hidden method injectInputEvent but I don't know **how to access injectInputEvent  and compile it?**

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of larger group - `rootViewController.dispatchTouchEvent` (instead of `activity.rootViewController`) works like a charm.

Comment: How can rootViewController be obtained?

Answer (score 5):

```
dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, Xinput, Yinput, 0));
```

You do not need to specify a view, the event will register to the foreground activity. Replace Xinput and Yinput with your values.